# Remote access to Ubuntu 18 not working from Win 10 with TeamViewer

Tags: 18.04, connection, teamviewer

I have two PCs: a Ubuntu 18.04 desktop and Windows 10 desktop.  Teamviewer is loaded on both.

Ubuntu18 can send chat messages to Win10, and Win10 can send chat messages to Ubuntu18.

I can remote Ubuntu18 to Win10 with TeamViewer and do all kinds of work.

However, I can't remote from Win10 desktop to my Ubuntu18 desktop.  This is the message I get: *"Connection could not be established."*

Obviously, I did something wrong and/or didn't set an option.  I'm just a Joe User, so please use layman's terms.

Comment: I tried disabling ufw, but that didn't work.  I'm going to give rdp a whirl.

Comment: rdp didn't work.  In fact, it set me back so to speak.  I encountered all kinds of problems and strange behaviors.  It got to the point that I upgraded from 18.04 to 19.04.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu doesn't contain Remote Desktop Protocol server on default install. If you like to use windows remote desktop, you need to install and configure rdp server to your computer.

Here is an explanation on Ubuntu wiki:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/xrdp

Comment: As far as I know TeamViewer does not use RDP server. The TeamViewer app acts as client as well as server.

Comment: why do we need xrdp for? after all its only works only on local network!